# How to call/reference Crystal Reports from .Net Core

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a visual studio solution that has several projects in it.

- Solution

  - Domain Layer (Class Library > .Net Core 2.2)

    - Holds all the database models
  - EntityFramework (Class Library > .Net Core 2.2)

    - Holds all the interaction with the database.  I reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore
  - Presentation Layer (WPF Windows Application > .Net Core 3.1)

    - Is the main interaction for the application

I'm at the point where I need to integrate reporting and printing of reports.  I've always used Crystal Reports for my applications (with good success).  However, since Crystal requires Framework 4.5 I can't figure out how to make that work.

I've created my Reporting objects and tested them.  They work great in their own standalone solution.  Once I reference the Framework app in my Core app I break.  In particular I break when I attempt to create a Crystal 'ReportDocument' object .  I've seen all over SO (and tested) you can't mix a .Net Core with .Net Framework because of the different DLLs.

Any suggestions on how I can get reporting/printing to work?  I'm not picky when it comes to Crystal Reports either.

Answer (score 5):

You are out of luck, because it is not supported. I would encourage you looking into other alternatives

From the Crystal Reports vendor website:

> So update your Core Project to the full 4.7.1 and it should work. I just install 4.7.1 and it works for my existing ASP.NET project that was set to 4.0.
>
> To be clear, Framework 2.0 Core is NOT supported

Source: [Crystal Reports in ASP .NET Core 2.0](https://answers.sap.com/questions/318288/crystal-reports-in-asp-net-core-20.html)

Comment: It is quite clear that Don at SAP do not understand what .Net Core is, since he think it's just another name for the .Net Framework Client Profile. Hopefully this has changed since that reply was from 2018. :)

Comment: @JeffNichols This is the answer. You should consider marking this question answered.

Answer (score 3):

How about you rethink your approach a bit. Do you really have to bundle everything to a single monolithic application?

Have you considered some separation of concern? What I'm trying to say is that you can abstract away your reporting service to a separate project/service and pass the data you need over let's say the wire - as an example.

Then you can build your application logic as you please.
My line of though is:

- sln

  - UI
  - API ?
  - Domain
  - Infra
- sln

  - API (wcf/gRPC/REST)
  - reporting service

Also you might want to consider gRPC, it can probably integrate with your legacy code if you have any.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/grpc-for-wcf-developers/migrate-wcf-to-grpc
- https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eBooks/tree/master/archives/grpc-for-wcf-developers
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=76X9oo-LlUY