# ASP.NET Core Crystal Reports integration

Tags: asp.net-core, crystal-reports

I developed a web application using ASP.NET webforms technology and it contains lots of reports designed by Crystal Reports.

I want to convert my project to ASP.NET Core technology, but I have a problem that's ASP.NET Core does not support Crystal Reports. I searched Google for any help, but did not find any.

I have almost 300 reports. Can you please suggest how to integrate these Crystal Reports with an ASP.NET Core web application?

Answer (score 3):

Crystal Reports does not support .net core, .net 5 or 6, and does not have any immediate plans to support .net core. They offer a couple solutions:

1. switch to java
2. hosts the reports it a 4.8 web application, and reverse proxy to it from you asp.net core application.

option 2 is probably your best.

note: .net core applications, nor .net standard libraries, can not call a 4.8 dll.

see thread:

https://answers.sap.com/questions/13029137/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-and-net-core-5-a.html

Answer (score 1):

One way around this is to decouple the report generation process from the .NET Core process.

For example, the .NET Core process can insert a record into a ***Report_Job*** table. That table can include information about not just the rpt file but also parameters and processing options.

Another process can monitor that table, trigger the reports, and remove/update the job records.

There are 3rd-party Crystal Reports tools that can do that (including the ability to update the database based on success/failure of the report job. So no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score -1):

Searched and as you say there is no hope for asp.net core (ref:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62057447/how-to-call-reference-crystal-reports-from-net-core ).

But you can do this by achieving :

1. Add a .net project which supports Crystal report (framework 4.7.1 or read the article - https://answers.sap.com/questions/318288/crystal-reports-in-asp-net-core-20.html) and add all reports in this project. You can add, modify, preview (or test) etc.
2. Now give the reference in your main application and call report from your code, so this way you can do this.

I have done the same with Telerik report. Good thing that it supports .net core. but having issues to add directly, so add in another project, give reference and then call from main project. Another good thing with this approach is when we go in live/production, as reports having in the different project, we can modify report(s) in designer and publish the report project dll only (not required to publish all projects).